# Multi Module Project with maven in Spring

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, microservices, multi-module

I have a project in spring boot with maven and It has 5 module with 1 parent module.

> **Module Structure**

```
 <modules>
    <module>service-app</module>
    <module>admin-app</module>
    <module>service-api</module>
    <module>admin-api</module>
    <module>mail-api</module>
    <module>storage-api</module>
</modules>



    1. admin-app = {<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
}
 2. service-api={
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
}
 3. service-app={
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
}
```

I tried to add new module and I have created but when I run program it returned errors. My new module is named storage-api there are its application.properties file some config params. When I want to use them in classes of storage-api. with @Value annotation it did not see them.
in this case How I can fix it problem

Answer (score 0):

Without information it is hard to guess, but I assume that your module `pom.xml` needs to reference its parent `pom.xml` like:

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>your parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>parent version</version>
</parent>
```

Just look it up from the working ones.